# Dynamic Google map zoom getBounds() undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this piece of javascript code

```
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var latlongcollection = new Array();
            // some more code to push latlng objects into latlongcollection
    map.setCenter(latlongcollection[0]);

    for(latlong in latlongcollection){
        map.getBounds().extend(latlong);
     }

     map.fitBounds(map.getBounds());
```

But everytime its giving me error map.getBounds() is undefined. center is set and even. zoom is set before I call map.getBounds(). Please help

Answer (score 2):

Try using a new [google.maps.LatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLngBounds) object instead of map.getBounds():

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
// note: this for/in loop is erronous
//for(latlong in latlongcollection){
//    bounds.extend(latlong);
//}
for ( var i = 0,len=latlongcollection.length;i<len;i++) {
    bounds.extend( latlongcollection[ i ] );
}
map.fitBounds( bounds );
```

Also, the for loop you use is bad in conjunction with arrays. A for/in on an array will loop not only over indexed values, but also properties and methods. So you will be extending you bounds with .length and .push and so on. This alone might've also caused the bug. Always read for/in loops as:

```
for property in object
```

Which includes methods and so on.